# Build Angular Template from VS2019 Community Error

Tags: angular, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

This is the first step try to publish the project which create from `VS2019` `Angular` template.
I just create the new project and build the `Angular` .
I have follow `Angular` to install `node-v14.15.4-x64` and
run

1. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`

It have success to build the project without any error.

But when I do publish, I get the below error
Invalid static method invocation syntax: "

> [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::FindRootFolderWhereAllFilesExist($(_VCTargetsPathFolders),
> $(_RelativeToolsetFiles))". Method
> 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.FindRootFolderWhereAllFilesExist'
> not found. Static method invocation should be of the form:
> $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`,
> `b`)).
> [C:\Users\developer\source\repos\WebApplication1\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]  WebApplication1 C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.props

Can I know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following suggestions

**1)** Close VS, open **Developer Command prompt for VS2019** as **Administrator**

first type `-u` with `gacutil` for these dlls:

```
gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll"

gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll"

gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll"

gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll"

gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"

gacutil /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll"
```

then restart VS to test again.

**2)** If the first step does not work, try the `-i` with `gacutil`:

Close VS, open open **Developer Command prompt for VS2019** as **Administrator**

```
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll"
    
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll"
    
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll"
    
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll"
    
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"
    
gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll"
```

**3)** If these do not help, please try to [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) from vs_installer.